# Prevent upscaling Adobe AIR app on iPad Pro 12.9"

Tags: ipad, air, adobe

My app is showing upscaled 2048x1536 instead of 2732x2048. I suspect I need to change the app xml somehow, but can not find any info on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out. The launch image for the iPad app needs to be 2372x2048.

This will define the resolution in the app itself.